# Display latest temperature by location quickly

Tags: php, mysql

The Table I have has temperatures, locations and datetime and other data that isn't currently used.  Message is the temperature and locationmap is where the sensor is ie, lounge, kitchen, outside!)

Query :

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM    
    temperatures t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        locationmap
        , MAX(timeof) AS timeof
    FROM
        temperatures
    GROUP BY
        locationmap
      ) AS t2
ON t1.locationmap = t2.locationmap AND t1.timeof = t2.timeof
WHERE
    DATE(t1.timeof) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND CURDATE()";
```

Resulting PHP code to display current temperatures;

```
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['locationmap']. " - ". $row['message']. " @". $row['timeof'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Just want it to display the latest temperature for each location, which it currently does, but I was wondering if this the best optimised query for speed, as at the moment it takes 7secs to display results!? Mind u I have a slow server, but I'm the only user.

Thx.

FYI.

[image: Data types]
[image: indexes]
[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Can't say without table create statements, more information about indexes and storage engine

And please make your SQL code more readable in your PHP code, It's damn hard to read like this.

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM    
    temperatures t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        locationmap
        , MAX(timeof) AS timeof
    FROM
        temperatures
    GROUP BY
        locationmap
      ) AS t2
ON t1.locationmap = t2.locationmap AND t1.timeof = t2.timeof
WHERE
    DATE(t1.timeof) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND CURDATE()
```

The same query but more readable

And thanks for the minus 1, because i tryed to help...

This query should run sightly faster

```
SELECT
    t1.locationmap
    , t1.message
    , t1.timeof
FROM    
    temperatures AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        locationmap
        , MAX(timeof) AS timeof
    FROM
        temperatures
    GROUP BY
        locationmap
      ) AS t2
ON t1.locationmap = t2.locationmap AND t1.timeof = t2.timeof
WHERE
    DATE(t1.timeof) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND CURDATE()
```

And make sure you have a covering BTREE (if you use MyISAM or innodb indexes are already BTREE) index on locationmap, timeof and message (optional) (be sure you build the index like this)
Please note that inserts, updates and deleted run sightly slower because of the covering index. 
So try to multiinsert to keep the speed up.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, have fixed my question to reflect easier reading of the query. I found that your new query was slower than my previous query. Yours ran at about 14secs whereas mine was 7secs. Table is setup as Innodb. The indexes are only setup for the ID, sorry newbie to mysql, do I just add another index for locationmap, timeof & message? I will do some research in the meantime. (Have added some screenshots of the table and indexes to my question)

Comment: A index on locationmap, timeof, message would help but i think you also should change your table structure. The column types arn't optimal for your data requirement.